# XAML Binding objects within an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to implement custom routes to the [XAMLMapControl](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/)  that will have selectable and movable points (the sample map point) and polylines connecting them and that could be turned on/off via visibility property. I have a class Route and a custom user control for it that should spawn both the polylines and the points from the route class that I send to it. I send the route objects to it via an array of routes. Problem is that i can't get it to actually fetch the data and render the points and polylines.
Here is my RouteControl.XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Map_Test.RouteControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:map="clr-namespace:MapControl;assembly=MapControl.WPF">
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="PointItemStyle" TargetType="map:MapItem" >
        <Setter Property="map:MapPanel.Location" Value="{Binding Location}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="map:MapItem">
                <Canvas>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="labelBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.7" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="selectedPath" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.7" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="selectedPath" Fill="White" Opacity="0">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Transparent">
                        <Path.Stroke>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/>
                        </Path.Stroke>
                        <Path.Data>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Grid Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="-8">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="labelBackground" Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
                        <!--local:OutlinedText Margin="1" OutlineThickness="1.5" Text="{Binding Name}"/-->
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<map:MapPanel>
    <map:MapPolyline Locations="{Binding Locations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                     Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                     StrokeThickness="3"/>
    <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PointItemStyle}"
                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                             SelectionMode="Extended"
                             MouseLeftButtonDown="PathMouseLeftButtonDown"
                             MouseLeftButtonUp="PathMouseLeftButtonUp"
                             MouseMove="PathMouseMove"/>       
</map:MapPanel>
```

My Route class

```
    public class RoutePoint : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private Location location;
    public Location Location
    {
        get { return location; }
        set
        {
            location = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => location);
        }
    }
}

public class Route : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<RoutePoint> Points { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<Location> Locations{ get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public Route()
    {
        Locations = new BindableCollection<Location>();
        Points = new ObservableCollection<RoutePoint>();
        Visible = true;
        Location = new Location();
    }
}
```

}

I create the object like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RouteTemplate">
        <local:RouteControl DataContext="Routes"></local:RouteControl>
    </DataTemplate>
...
<map:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RouteTemplate}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"/>
```

How to get acces to the Locations array and the RoutePoints array in every object of the Route collection from xaml?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, it's impossible to know for sure what the actual problem is. It's not clear from the question even what _"it"_ is that you think _"needs a style"_. An `ItemsControl` can have data items of differing types; just provide appropriate `DataTemplate` objects for each. Or you can implement a [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) if the basic template functionality doesn't work for you

Comment: @PeterDuniho I just didn't want to get an absurd amount of code in here and maybe was unclear with the question, sorry. The root of the problem is that i can't separate the Locations array and the Points array. If I feed the template something like Routes/Points it will only work on the first class in the route array. By "it" i meant the RouteControl itself. It only has sub-styles for routes and polylines but not for the Routes as a whole

Comment: _"I just didn't want to get an absurd amount of code "_ -- and nor should you. No one wants to see an _absurd_ amount of code. But the question isn't clear without the _right_ amount of code. :( _"it will only work on the first class in the route array"_ -- you can mix types in the `ItemsSource` for an `ItemsControl`...the `TargetType` for the template, or the logic in a `DataTemplateSelector`, will choose the appropriate template for each object in the source.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I believe we are misunderstanding each other. I don't have different types to combine. Both Points and Locations are an attribute of the Route class. XAML doesnt let you directly access an attribute of every class in the class array. If i set DataTemplates for points and locations (which are already set and work if they are not incapsulated in the Route class) they wont apply to my array of Routes that I am binding

Comment: _"we are misunderstanding each other"_ -- yes, of course we are. That's the problem with a poorly-written question: _it's hard to understand_. Please provide a good code example, as described in the link I provided earlier. Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for additional information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I reviewed my code and the code I provided and came to the conclustion that all the other code in my project is completely irrelevant. The only line i did not add that directly adds to the question is Routes = new ObservableCollection<Route>(); but i just stated that in text. If I described the question in one sentace it would sound like this: "How to get acces to the Locations array and the RoutePoints array in every object of the Route collection from xaml?". Sorry for the inconvenience but I personally find the question itself pretty clear.

Comment: _"I personally find the question itself pretty clear"_ -- All due respect, how clear _you_ find the question is irrelevant. You have vastly more context than anyone else, so it's much easier for you to find it "clear". You need to consider the question from the perspective of someone who knows nothing about the issue, something you obviously have not done. A _complete_ code example is so important that numerous articles, including the links I've provided, emphasize it as a critical component of a good question. You have a lot to learn about _asking questions_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
Instead of making a custom control I made a custom style with the controls I have in a panel.
This is how it looks

```
   <Style x:Key="RouteTemplate"  TargetType="map:MapItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visible}" Value="True"></DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="map:MapItem">
                    <map:MapPanel>
                    <map:MapPolyline Locations="{Binding Locations}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                        <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PointItemStyle}"
                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                             SelectionMode="Extended" AllowDrop="True"/>
                    </map:MapPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And I bind it like this

```
<map:MapItemsControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RouteTemplate}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"/>
```